# A button that can switch from increment to decrement at random, possible or not?

Tags: javascript, html, button, increment, decrement

quick question: Is it possible to set a button that can increment and or decrement a number as it is clicked? I want to know if such a feature is possible and if so, how?

Comment: Literally no, but with a button, you can start executing a script doing what you need.

Comment: "literally no"??? You can do many things when clicking a button if you have added an event listener to it. @Teemu I think you are being cryptic here. Poor question but still

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [Flip a coin](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+flip+a+coin+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan You can submit a form with a button, but that's all what a button can do on its own. As you said, you'd need an event listener, and a script to handle that event. So, it's literally not possible for a button to increment or decrement a number.

Comment: @Teemu Question was tagged JavaScript so we were likely allowed to use JS. And the button submitting to the server could have the server return incremented or decremented values...

Comment: @mplungjan The tongue in the cheek of course, and it's yet a better answer than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068527/1169519).

Comment: @Teemu Lol......

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` to decide whether you are going to increment or not:

```js
var counter = 0,
    $counter = document.getElementById('counter'),
    $myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

$myBtn.addEventListener('click', incrementOrDecrement);

function incrementOrDecrement() {
  var shouldIncrement = Math.random() > 0.5; // 50% chances of incrementing
  counter += shouldIncrement ? 1 : -1;
  $counter.innerText = counter;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Change counter</button>
<h2 id="counter">0</h2>
```